# Systemd can't find unit but can `cat`/`status` it?

Tags: systemd

Systemd seems to not be able to find this unit when attempting to start it, but all other operations seem to work.

```
bash-4.2# systemctl daemon-reload   

bash-4.2# systemctl start xyzzy.service
Failed to start xyzzy.service: Unit not found.

bash-4.2# systemctl cat xyzzy
# /etc/systemd/system/xyzzy.service
[Unit]
BindsTo=aabbcc.service
After=aabbcc.service

[Service]
User=xyzzy
Group=xyzzy
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/opt/xyzzy/scripts/xyzzy_start.sh
RestartSec=1
StartLimitInterval=5

[Install]
WantedBy=aabbcc.service

bash-4.2# systemctl status xyzzy
● xyzzy.service - xyzzy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xyzzy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 19 21:28:11 ......
Dec 19 21:28:39 ...... systemd[1]: Stopping xyzzy...
Dec 19 21:28:39 ...... systemd[1]: Stopped xyzzy.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

bash-4.2# systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/xyzzy.service
Error: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit not found.
Failed to create xyzzy.service/start: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `inactive (dead)` usually means the service started and exited.  Because you are using Type=simple , systemd does not do further monitoring of the service's health.

Comment: @user10489 Yes, the process is dead because I killed it. But a subsequent `start` or `restart` should bring it back up again. I don't see anything in the docs indicating that it wouldn't.

Comment: What's the status of `aabbcc.service` using `systemctl status`? Maybe make `RestartSec=5` too ans see if that makes any difference